# Como abrir urls externas com as funções php

Tags: php

Ao tentar abrir uma url com a função `file_get_contents()` recebo o seguinte erro

> file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse erro?

---

Ao usar a função `phpinfo()` aparece que o suporte ao OpenSSL esta desativado e tem que baixar a .dll mais já baixei coloquei no diretório como na foto abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para ver os tipos de conexões permitidas, execute o script:  echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump(stream_get_wrappers()); 
echo '</pre>';

Comment: tenta fazer `phpinfo()` e mostra as extensões  ativadas

Comment: OpenSSL support -  disabled (install ext/openssl)

Comment: Versão errada de DLL muito provavelmente. Se tem certeza que está habilitada no .ini e a versão é correta, clique em [edit] e acrescente mais detalhes na pergunta. Se o problema é o .ini, seria o caso de indicar qual resposta resolveu. Da forma como está, creio que o problema não pode ser reproduzido (ao menos pelo atual enunciado).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu diretório de extensões no php.ini pode estar referenciando um caminho relativo errado, já tive um problema com isso.

Tente verificar se a diretiva "extension_dir" está referenciando o local certo.
Tente substituir pelo endereço absoluto. Ex.: extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro acontece porque tens uma extensão **desativada** na configuração do php

Abre o teu ficheiro `php.ini` procura por esta linha e retira o `;` da frente dessa extensão, exemplo:

```
;extension=php_openssl
```

**muda para:**

```
extension=php_openssl
```

**Salva a edição do arquivo e reinicia o servidor** e o erro deve ser corrigido.

Comment: Não funcionou deu Not found php_openssl.dll

Comment: tenta baixar a dll e mete no directório das extensões

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_openssl.dll' - %1 n´┐¢o ´┐¢ um aplicativo Win32 v´┐¢lido.
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br /> aparece o seguinte erro

Comment: baixei e continuou

Comment: @LeoneCerqueira dll da versão ou arquitetura errada seria interessante verificar e baixar a correta

Comment: @LeoneCerqueira verifica tambem se baixaste a dll para windows e não para linux...